# regular expression to differentiate three different fields in R

Tags: regex, r

I am struggling to come up with a regular expression in R to differentiate below three fields

```
[C/T]GA, A[T/C]G, GA[G/A]
```

Basically i want to see how many of the SNPs falls into each of the above categories of codons (1st position, 2nd postion and 3rd position).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Upendra

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the input and what is the desired output?  Please show a minimal example exactly.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear but Martin Morgan was able to figure out what my intention is and his code worked.

Comment: -1 for incomplete description and not improving it when asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it enough to find the index of the opening `[`? then

```
> x = c("[C/T]GA", "A[T/C]G", "GA[G/A]", "GAG")
> regexpr("[", x, fixed=TRUE)
```

returns 1, 2, 3 or -1 (if not found).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to count three different categories:

```
codons <- paste0( sample(c("G", "C", "T", "A"), 1000, repl=TRUE), 
                    sample(c("G", "C", "T", "A"), 1000, repl=TRUE), 
                    sample(c("G", "C", "T", "A"), 1000, repl=TRUE) )

 ev1 <- length( grep("^[CT]GA", codons) ) 
       # number matching either CGA or TGA
 ev2 <- length( grep("^A[TC]G", codons) ) 
       # number matching either ATG or ACG 
 ev3 <- length( grep("^GA[GA] ", codons) ) 
       # number matching either GAG or GAA 

head(codons)

> (ev1 <- length( grep("^[CT]GA", codons) ) )
[1] 22
>  (ev2 <- length( grep("^A[TC]G", codons) ) )
[1] 26
>  (ev3 <- length( grep("^GA[GA]", codons) ) )
[1] 43
```